# How to do reverse DNS lookup and get the regular domain name instead of a generic domain name

Tags: php, networking, dns

i'm developing a PHP app and i came across this problem.

I have a database table that keeps the network traffic logs and i'm creating reports from those logs by analyzing them in my app and i need to get domain names from ips to show users what websites are most commonly used. The problem is all i have are destination and source ports and ips. I've written a code that filters these logs and gets the ones that have 443 as the source port for getting data that is about the web. The problem now is that when i run a reverse dns lookup for the destination_ip, i get the generic domain name of that ip. Is there a way to get the real domain name instead of the generic domain name? Any help is appreciated.

Chatgpt says there is no way

Comment: It sound very much like you don't really understand how this all works, which is understandable. I would propose to go back to the very beginning: _"I have a database table that keeps the network traffic logs"_, are you creating these logs yourself? If so, how? If not, what generates them? Perhaps a few lines from the log would be useful for us to see what they look like? It would also be good to know more about your web server and how you have configured your domains.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "real" vs "generic" domain names? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: regular domain name is "youtube.com", generic domain name is "sof02s46-in-f14.1e100.net" @ADyson

Comment: There's nothing "generic" about that, it's unclear what you mean by that terminology. It's simply two different names. One could be considered more user-friendly than the other but there is no technical difference between them. So yes some servers/IPs can map to more than one hostname. Therefore getting back to a specific hostname from the IP alome is not necessarily easy, as there's no way to know which one should be returned. Take a look at the answer below by AbraCadaver

Comment: This all was the reason I wanted to go back to the traffic logs in the database. In the end I hope that the database contains the domains that were used in some fashion. Since we have no information at all, on what these logs look like, or who/what made them, we cannot explore that further. You can still [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78108647/edit) and add this information.

Comment: yall as clueless as i am lol the guy said i didnt understand this the thing is yall understand it less than me lol google uses a cluster of servers for load balancing and handling traffic more efficiently thus uses these domains this dude asked my about my database table which has no relation whatsoever with my question. Stackoverflow users still under the IQ of 60 i see. Enjoy yall day.

Comment: You're the one who mentioned the database logs. You were asked to show us an example of what's in them in case there's something there you could use to get the info you're interested in, because reverse DNS isn't going to help you - as we've explained. So the database log info could easily be relevant. What's definitely _not_ particularly relevant is knowing that the site is on a Google cluster - such an architecture is pretty standard for web hosting, you'd find it in most providers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using DNS.  An `A` record translate a hostname `www.domain.com` to an IP address.  A `PTR` record translates an IP address to a hostname.  There should be only one `PTR` record, however, if there is more than one, then it is unpredictable (random) which will be returned.

For example there may be multiple `A` records:

```
www.domain.com          1.1.1.2
mail.domain.com         1.1.1.2
```

But only one `PTR` record:

```
1.1.1.2.in-addr.arpa    domain.com
```

The only reliable way to get the actual host would be from the HTTP Host Header or other headers, if you are capturing those.